# Question on tags

Tags: tags

Please help me figure this scenario out. I have a paragraph with tags in it. I want my user to insert proper values in the tags, and not be able to type random stuff. Are there any patterns that enable such organized tag usage? Any advice would be much appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You could use the autocomplete pattern. This is quite popular and depending on what framework your using, you should be able to get to running out of box.

https://material-ui.com/demos/autocomplete/

If you want more than one tag per iput, you can look up using chips.

https://material-ui.com/demos/chips/

Here is a sample:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Check out Natural Language Forms:
https://www.jroehm.com/2014/01/ui-pattern-natural-language-form/